# Is there a package in R to monitor the use of resources (CPU, RAM, etc) and get a result at the end?

Tags: r, performance, memory, rstudio

Im trying to find if there is any package in R Studio to start monitoring the use of resources (CPU, RAM, etc) in my PC. I'm doing this because I need to know this information for every scripts that runs in Rstudio, so I would like to know if anyone knows something about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bench package.

```
> library(bench)
> 
> mark(source('example.R'), iterations = 1)
# A tibble: 1 x 13
  expression               min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result           memory             time           gc              
  <bch:expr>          <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>           <list>             <list>         <list>          
1 source("example.R")    284us    284us     3516.    11.8KB        0     1     0      284us <named list [2]> <Rprofmem [5 x 3]> <bench_tm [1]> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Here I forced it to make only one iteration. But you can set it to any number you like for more accurate results.

Comment: Oh, I will try this! Thanks!